# How to read copied html text from clipboard with its html tags?

Tags: .net, html, tags, clipboard, paste

When a user selects and copies a text from a web page, I need to get that text with all the html tags included so that I can select some specific attributes etc.

Is it possible to read it from .NET application?

thanks

Comment: Maybe 'View Source' first, some browsers allow 'View Selected Source' which sounds like exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Clipboard.GetText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597034.aspx) method will retrieve HTML content from the clipboard:

```
var htmlData = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.TextDataFormat.Html);
```

You can check if the clipboard contains HTML with the [`Clipboard.ContainsText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597027.aspx) method.